# Anscombe-like datasets with the same box and whiskers plot (mean/std/median/MAD/min/max)

Tags: regression, descriptive-statistics, curve-fitting, estimators

EDIT: As this question has been inflated, a summary: finding different meaningful and interpretable datasets with the same mixed statistics (mean, median, midrange and  their associated dispersions, and regression).

The Anscombe quartet (see [Purpose of visualizing high dimensional data?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9038/purpose-of-visualizing-high-dimensional-data/9130#9130https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9038/purpose-of-visualizing-high-dimensional-data/9130#9130)) is a famous example of four $x$-$y$ datasets, with the same marginal mean/standard deviation (on the four $x$ and the four $y$, separately) and the same [OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) linear fit, regression and residual sum of squares, and correlation coefficient $R^2$. The $\ell_2$-type statistics (marginal and joint) are thus the same, while the  datasets are  quite different.

[image: Anscombe's quartet]

EDIT (from OP comments) Leaving the  small dataset size apart, let me propose some interpretations. Set 1 can be seen as a standard linear (affine, to be correct) relationship with distributed noise. Set 2 shows a clean relationship which could be the acme of a higher-degree fit. Set 3 shows a clear linear statistical dependence with one outlier. Set 4 is more tricky: the  attempt to "predict" $y$ from $x$ seems bound to failure. The design of $x$ may reveal an hysteresis phenomenon with an insufficient range of values, a quantization effect (the $x$ could be quantizied too heavily), or the user has switched the dependent and independent variables.

So $\ell_2$ summary features hide very different behaviors. Set 2 could be better dealt with a polynomial fit. Set 3 with outlier-resistant methods ($\ell_1$ or like), as well as Set 4. One might wonder whether other cost functions or discrepancy indicators could settle, or at least improve dataset discrimination. EDIT (from OP comments): the blog post [Curious Regressions](http://davegiles.blogspot.fr/2011/03/curious-regressions.html) state that:

> Incidentally, I'm told that Frank Anscombe never revealed just how he
>   came up with these sets of data. If you think it`s an easy task to get
>   all of the summary statistics and the regression results the same,
>   then give it a try!

In [Datasets constructed for a purpose similar to that of Anscombe's quartet](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80196/datasets-constructed-for-a-purpose-similar-to-that-of-anscombes-quartet), several interesting datasets are given, for instance with the same quantile-based histograms. I did not see a mixture of meaningful relationship and mixed statistics.

My  question is: **are there bivariate (or trivariate, to keep visualization) Anscombe-like  datasets such that, in addition to having the  same $\ell_2$-type statistics**:

- their plots are interpretable as a relationship  between $x$ and  $y$, as if one were looking for a law between measurements,
- they possess the same (more robust) $\ell_1$ marginal properties (same median and median of absolute deviation),
- they have the same bounding boxes: same min, max (and hence $\ell_\infty$-type mid-range and mid-span statistics).

Such datasets would have the same "box-and-whiskers" plot [summaries](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/numsum.htm) (with min, max, median, median absolute deviation/MAD, mean and std) on each variable, and would still be quite different in interpretation.

It would be even more interesting if some least absolute regression were the same for the datasets (but maybe I am already asking too much). They  could serve as a *caveat* when talking about robust vs. not robust regression, and help keep in mind Richard Hamming's quote:

> The purpose of computing is insight, not numbers

EDIT (from OP comments) Similar issues are dealt with in [Generating Data with Identical Statistics but Dissimilar Graphics](https://dx.doi.org/10.1198/000313007X220057), Sangit Chatterjee & Aykut Firata, The American Statistician, 2007, or Cloning data: generating datasets with exactly the same multiple linear regression fit, J. Aust. N.-Z. Stat. J. 2009.

In  Chatterjee (2007), the  purpose is to generate novel $(x,y)$ pairs with the same means and standard deviations from initial dataset, while maximizing different "discrepancy/dissimilarity" objective functions. As these functions can be non-convex or non-differentiable, they use genetic algorithms (GA). Important steps consist in ortho-normalization, which is very consistent with preserving mean and (unit-)variance. The paper's figures (half the  paper content) superimpose input and  GA output data. My opinion is that GA outputs lose a lot of the  original intuitive interpretation.

And technically, neither the median nor the  midrange is preserved, and the paper does not mention renormalization procedures that would preserve $\ell_2$, $\ell_1$ and $\ell_\infty$ stats.

Comment: If you're just after univariate data sets with the same boxplots, I gave a set in an answer to a question a while back, based on the development in a paper. Hold on, I'll dig it out. (edit) ...  [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137965/box-and-whisker-plot-for-multimodal-distribution/137982#137982). It's easy to make more data sets with the same properties...  I address that in another answer, [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135737/will-two-distributions-with-identical-5-number-summaries-always-have-the-same-sh/135760#135760).

Comment: However, on reflection, I suppose now that you're not after univariate data sets with the same boxplots, but instead seek bivariate data sets whose $x$'s and $y$'s all have the same set of two boxplots, *and* which have the same least squares line -- is that right?

Comment: The  digging was useful to me, especially on the  skewness part. Yet I am indeed looking at more "natural" looking bivariate (or  more) plots, with dependencies between $x$ and $y$. A similar "robust" fit would be a plus. I have edited and hopefully clarified the  question

Comment: [Chatterjee & Firat (*The American Statistician*, 2007)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27643902?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), linked to in [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/80198/1352) to [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/80196/1352), provide a rather general genetic algorithm you should be able to adapt in a straightforward way to your purposes.

Comment: I don't know that I'd interpret data set 4 as an *absence* of a relationship, but merely that because of the "design" (the layout of the x), the impression of a relationship is (dangerously) predicated on only a single observation. You *won't* be able to have a data set that fulfills all your conditions that looks much like data set 4, (unless they all look like data set 4).

Comment: I wrote "possible", but effectively, my formulation deserves criticism. Other potential interpretations: an hysteresis phenomenon with an insufficient range of values, a quantization effect (the $x$ could be quantizied too heavily). I'll update the mention.

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate but as far as I can see the indicated duplicate didsn't even come close to actually answering this question, so I have reopened. (Feel free to discuss disagreement, of course.)

Comment: From what I understand in Chatterkee 2007 paper, the point clouds at the end al least lack meaningful visual structure. Updates on the OP planned over the week-end after more digging

Comment: One thing: anyone attempting to produce a set like the Anscombe data (besides noting my comment that data set D won't be possible) -- you'll probably want a bit  more than 11 observations as well.

Comment: The plots are examples of population moments being meaningless when distribution moments are ignored. Mean, standard deviation, skewness, and other population moments do not correspond to the expected values, standard deviations, skewness and other moments of the distributions that best describe those populations. When the plots above are looked at as distributions of x-values and y-values, they are all different and therefore have different distribution moments. This is worse that just ignoring residual structure, which was perhaps the point, one can ignore neither with impunity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be concrete, I'm considering the problem of creating two datasets each of which suggests a relationship but the relationship of each is different, and yet also have approximately the same:

- mean *x*
- mean *y*
- SD *x*
- SD *y*
- median *x*
- median *y*
- minimum *x*
- minimum *y*
- maximum *x*
- maximum *y*
- median absolute deviation from the median of *x*
- median absolute deviation from the median of *y*
- coefficients from simple linear regression of *y* on *x*

Perhaps this is cheating, but one way to make this problem a lot easier is to use a dataset where the best-fitting line is the *x*-axis, $\operatorname{mean} y = 0$, and $\min y = -\max y$. Then we can just flip the data vertically to get something suggestive of a clearly distinct distribution but where all the above statistics are preserved.

Consider, for example,

\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
x & 0 & \tfrac{1}{9} & \tfrac{2}{9} & \tfrac{3}{9} & \tfrac{4}{9} & \tfrac{5}{9} & \tfrac{6}{9} & \tfrac{7}{9} & \tfrac{8}{9} & 1 \\
\hline
y & -1 & -\tfrac{1}{2} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{2} &  1 & 1 & \tfrac{1}{2} & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{2} & -1
\end{array}

which has a upward-V-shaped graph like this:

[image: graph]

Replace $y$ with $-y$ and you get a downward V with all the same statistics, and not just approximately, but exactly.

Comment: Nice contribution. Indeed, I fell the horizontal line is a bit of cheating wrt OLS. The flipping is a good idea, yet if the datasets are different, they remain similar. But I think you have a good idea, perhaps an "N" shape and a "W" shape in the same fashion could be the start of a path