# How to determine distribution from Sleep data min/max/mean values in R?

Tags: r, distributions, interquartile

I want to determine the distribution from the *[EMFIT QS](https://www.emfitqs.com/)* sleep data which gives only `min`, `max` and `mean` values for sleep clasess in R, in order to estimate quartiles. 
Types of sleep waves in the signal in Fig. 1. 
I know the thread answer [Finding Quartiles in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/134239/3017). 
Fig. 1 types of possible sleep waves (source Guyton Physiology).

[image]

Summary of the descriptive statistics given by the manufacturer given for one measurement session lasting 5-14 hours

```
dat.m <- structure(list(Vars = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Average ", 
"Max     ", "Min     "), class = "factor"), Sleep = c(7, 4, 10
), Awake = c(12L, 5L, 15L)), .Names = c("Vars", "Sleep", "Awake"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

> dat.m
      Vars Sleep Awake 
1 Average      7    12
2 Min          4     5
3 Max         10    15
```

Current method to estimate the quartiles is manual

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/44043313/54964
quartiles <- data.frame(Vars = c("Q1","Q3"), Sleep = c(6,8), 
                    Awake = c(9,13))
```

OS: Debian 8.7
R: 3.4.0 (backports)
Related therad: [Why this CSV data complicates with ggplot2 whisker plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44039066/54964)

Comment: Note that min, max and mean tell you very little about the quartiles -- see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236449/calculating-distribution-from-min-mean-and-max/236468?s=1|2.9133#236468) and similar issues occur as [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135737/will-two-distributions-with-identical-5-number-summaries-always-have-the-same-sh/135760#135760) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137965/box-and-whisker-plot-for-multimodal-distribution/137982#137982).

Comment: Please ask a more specific question; you'll need to make some assumptions to get much value from this. Why would your "rough proposal" make any sense? please explain your thinking.

Comment: @Glen_b Please, open again. I need to determine the underlying distiribution to propose anything about the quartiles.

Comment: The *first* link I gave already discusses the difficulty of trying to do this from just those values (if it was possible to determine the distribution from min, max and mean, finding quartiles would be easy); you edit has made it even more clearly a duplicate of that post. You need to bring information from *outside* the data (like knowledge of the kind of variable you're dealing with might suggest a parametric form, or subject area knowledge may give information about shape for example) to have any hope of doing very much at all.

Comment: @Glen_b Please, see the body and open. I made it more descriptive of the situation.

Comment: It's in a review queue (because you edited). I don't see enough new to make it distinct here, but others will decide.